# XML XElement / Linq replace values with data from dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xelement

Is there a way to replace all existing values from XML with values from dictionary using Linq? I'm using c#.

XML example:

```
<root>
  <node1> <--without attribute
    <subNode1>someTextValue</subNode1>
  </node1>
  <node2 name="myNode2"> <--With attribute (IMPORTANT!!!)
    <subNod1>someOtherTextValue</subNode1>
  </node2>
</root>


Dictionary<string, Hashtable> dataFromXML;
```

`dataFromXML Keys` from the example are `node1 (because here is note an attribute), myNode2 (because here is an attribute)`...

`dataFromXML Values` are subNodes.

Now lets say we make some value changes in some subNode and we want to update the XML.

How could I do this instead of looping with foreach???

Hope my question is clear defined.

### **EDIT**

What about XElement and the ReplaceWith funcation?

Best reagards.

Comment: Linq is primarily a "read-only" technology. To update an XML file you are going to need an XML writer of some type.

Comment: Although I suppose you could try this Update extension: http://www.hookedonlinq.com/UpdateOperator.ashx

Comment: From the way you are asking the question "we make some value changes in some subNode and we want to update the XML" it sounds like you would just be doing a query and then updating the First() or Single() result so I don't see why you would need a foreach for that. If what you mean is you want to update many SubNode1 values and you want to do it without a foreach then you could use LINQs ForEach opperator, but I'm not sure that is what you are asking.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Linq is not a read only technology, you can update data from an xelement...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can update the XDocument in the Linq query. Anyway will be easy to develop the foreach statement (trust me you will lose less time), and remember that the linq queries are traduced as loop statements so even if you only see one line of code, the loop actually exists...

Regards